# Widget not saved in sidebar (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, widget

Good evening, everyone. I've got such a task as creating a plugin that will create a widget that performs certain functions. Namely - to display the list of users from the database. 
Actually, the problem is that the widget created by the plugin, after updating - disappears from the sidebar.

```
    <?php 

/*
Plugin Name: Название плагина
Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
Description: Краткое описание плагина.
Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
Author: Имя автора плагина
Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
*/

/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Register widget with WordPress.
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'foo_widget', // Base ID
            esc_html__( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
            array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    /**
     * Front-end display of widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::widget()
     *
     * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
     * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
        }
        echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Back-end widget form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::form()
     *
     * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget::update()
     *
     * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
     * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
     *
     * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }

} // class Foo_Widget

// register Foo_Widget widget
function register_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );

?>
```

There is still such a point that if you put the standard widget creation code inside the plugin, it will save everything

```
<?php 

    /*
    Plugin Name: Название плагина
    Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
    Description: Краткое описание плагина.
    Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
    Author: Имя автора плагина
    Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
    */

    /
     * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
     */
    class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

  /
   * Register widget with WordPress.
   */
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
      'foo_widget', // Base ID
      esc_html__( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
      array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
  }

  /
   * Front-end display of widget.
   *
   * @see WP_Widget::widget()
   *
   * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
   * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
   */
  public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
      echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
    }
    echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }

  /
   * Back-end widget form.
   *
   * @see WP_Widget::form()
   *
   * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
   */
  public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
  }

  /
   * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
   *
   * @see WP_Widget::update()
   *
   * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
   * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
   *
   * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
   */
  public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
  }

    } // class Foo_Widget

    // register Foo_Widget widget
    function register_foo_widget() {
        register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );

    ?>
```

That is, it does not save only if there is a custom PhnP code.

And in case if you put the dummy and rewrite it with custom, it will be saved until the first change of theme or deactivation of the plugin.

Can you point to errors in my code?

Thank you for your attention.